# fscanf doesn't wait for input for stdin in assembly

Tags: gcc, assembly, scanf, nasm, stdin

I'm trying to get input from STDIN in assembly using fscanf C function but  the program doesn't stop for keyboard input.
Below the code:

```
global  _main
extern  _fscanf
section  .data
    text        db  '****',0
    strFormat   dd  '%s'
    stdIn       dd  0
section .text
_main:
    push    text
    push    strFormat
    push    dword[stdIn]
    call    _fscanf
    add     esp,12
        ret
```

I expect the prompt wait for the keyboard input but it doesn't.
I'm using NASM and GCC.  Below the command details:

```
C:\nasm-2.14.02\pgms>nasm testFscanf.asm -f elf

C:\nasm-2.14.02\pgms>gcc testFscanf.o -m32 -o testFscanf
```

Comment: _stdin_ is not the one from _stdio_ (you can use _scanf_ to not have to give it), the format is not ended by a null, your way to give the args is not compatible. Write the call in C then generate the assembler and look at

Comment: Which operating system are you programming for?

Comment: @fuz I'm using windows 7

Comment: @bruno why is not compatible the way I use to give the args? I use this same way for printf, scanf, and for managing file and it works fine.  I'm looking for replace fscanf instead of scanf because scanf allows writing memory more than the receiving field length is.

Comment: @DMR The problem is that your `stdIn` is not the same thing as the `stdin` variable of the libc.  You can't just make your own `stdIn` without knowing what you are doing.  And your `strFormat` is wrong too because you use `dd`, giving each character four bytes.  You also forgot to add a NULL terminator.  I recommend you to check out the assembly generated by the C compiler and to work with that.

Comment: @fuz: in NASM, `dd '%s'` is the same as `db '%', 's', 0, 0`.  It just pads the multi-character integer literal to a multiple of 4 bytes.  So that's actually totally fine, and includes the 0 terminator.  (This is a really obfuscated way to write it, though, and wastes an extra byte for a 2nd 0.)  And BTW, the name for ASCII `'\0'` is NUL, not NULL.  (I usually just describe it as a 0 terminator to sidestep any debate over NULL vs. NUL and whether either of those are appropriate.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for the clarification.  I know it's NUL though, I just made a typo.